# Proving $\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 2$ using strong induction

Tags: summation, induction

I just started learning proof by induction in class, but got a problem requiring proof by **strong** induction.

Here is the problem.

> **Prove by strong induction:** $$\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i = 2^{n+1} - 2$$

I've done the base, showing that the statement holds for $n=1$, $n=2$, and $n=3$. (I won't show the simple math here). For $n=k$, the statement would be $2^{k+1}-2$. But that's where I get stuck, as I'm still trying to grasp the concept of strong induction.

For $n=k+1$, do I do the following and simplify?

$$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} 2^i = \sum_{i=1}^k 2^i + 2^{(k+1)+1} - 2$$
$$=[2^{k+1}-2]+[2^{k+2}-2]$$
$$=\text{etc}\ldots?$$

Comment: Did you mean $2^{n+1}$ on the right side of your first equation?

Comment: I copied it exactly as it's written on this worksheet, but $2^{n+1}$ is definitely correct. Likely a typo. Thanks for the catch--I'll edit the original.

Comment: Have you tried using the fact that $2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n = 2^n+2^n$?

Comment: **You do not need strong induction here.** I would encourage you to read [what exactly is the difference between weak and strong induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction) to better understand the differences between weak/strong induction. Then see [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1193942/proving-sum-i-0n-2i-2n1-1-by-induction/1194534#1194534) for a proof of your claim using weak induction--it also points out that your problem here is really just a specific case of a more general problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For strong induction, a proof goes something like this:

Proof of a base case: here $n= 1$ will do:

$2 = 4 - 2$.

The only thing different between "strong" and "regular" induction is how we state the inductive step:

We assume that for ALL $n_0 \leq k < n$, the theorem holds, and then use that to show it holds for $k = n$. This means we have access to ANY previous non-negative integer $k$ in that range, not just "the previous integer", $n-1$.

In this case, that means we can assume the result for all $1 \leq k < n$.

Of course, since $k = n - 1 < n$, we can use that case, too.

So we have:

$\sum\limits_{i = 1}^n 2^i = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n-1} 2^i + 2^n = (2^n - 2) + 2^n = \dots ?$

Comment: So the essential difference between regular and strong induction is that in regular induction, you assume that the arbitrary $k$ is $n<k$, whereas in strong induction, the relationship is $k<n$, giving access to any integer $i<k<n$?

Comment: It probably would have been worth mentioning here that strong induction is not needed at all--from OP's question, it seems he may think it actually is important to use strong induction, but that clearly isn't the case.

Comment: In regular induction you go "step by step", using the $n-1$ case to prove the $n$ case. Thus if your base case is $n_0$, then $n_0$ proves $n_0 + 1$, and the $n_0 + 1$ case proves the $n_0 + 2$ case, etc. In strong induction, you are allowed to use *any case* between your base case and $n$. This is often helpful when you want to split $n$ into smaller factors, for example. The "$i$" in this problem, by the way, is just a "dummy variable" (used as an *index of summation*), and any other letter could be used.

Comment: @Daniel I was able to prove the statement using regular induction, but the problem specifically says to prove using strong induction in order to nail the concept. If only life made sense :(

Comment: @David That makes mich better sense now. I tried using $n-2$ as well and it worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: @Greg Some people simply choose to *always* use strong induction and that's fine, but the point is that it is really not necessary in this case. If you are learning weak/strong induction for the first time, I would expect a better problem from a teacher to highlight when/why strong induction needs to be used, and this problem is not one of those times. Did you look at the [weak vs. strong inducton](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1184541/what-exactly-is-the-difference-between-weak-and-strong-induction) link? One problem is proved with strong induction though only weak is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculation $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^i=\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^i+2^{(k+1)+1}-2$$ is false. What's true is that $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^i=\sum_{i=1}^k2^i+2^{k+1},$$ and $2^{k+1}\neq 2^{(k+1)+1}-2$ in general. You can apply the induction hypothesis to the first term on the right to get what you want, although this is normal induction, rather than strong induction.

Comment: Right, I understand how to prove the statement by regular induction, but it's the strong induction that I'm having trouble wrapping my mind around.

Comment: In that case, David addresses your question better. It's just that $k<k+1$, if if we can assume for all $<k+1$, we can certainly assume for $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose
$\sum_{i=1}^k 2^i = 2^{k+1} - 2
$
for all $k < n$.

Then,
choose *some* $k$ with $1 < k < n$.

$\begin{array}\\
\sum_{i=1}^n 2^i
&=\sum_{i=1}^k 2^i +\sum_{i=k+1}^n 2^i\\
&=2^{k+1} - 2 +2^k\sum_{i=k+1}^n 2^{i-k}\\
&=2^{k+1} - 2 +2^k\sum_{i=1}^{n-k} 2^{i}\\
&=2^{k+1} - 2 +2^k(2^{n-k+1}-2)\\
&=2^{k+1} - 2 +2^{n+1}-2^{k+1}\\
&=2^{n+1} - 2 \\
\end{array}
$

This is the 
only way I could think of
to use strong induction.

Answer (score -1):

We have to prove, $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}2^{i}=2^{n+1}-2$$
Step 1: Setting $n=1$ in the above equality, we get $$\sum_{i=1}^{1}2^{i}=2^{1+1}-2\iff 2=4-2\iff 2=2$$ hence it holds for $n=1$

Step 2: Assuming that it holds for $n=k$, we get $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i}=2^{k+1}-2$$

Step 3: Now, setting $n=k+1$ in the given equality, we get $$\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}2^{i}=2^{k+1+1}-2 $$$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i}+2^{k+1}=2^{k+2}-2$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i}=2.2^{k+1}-2-2^{k+1}$$ $$\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i}=2^{k+1}-2$$
Which is true from (2), hence it holds for $n=k+1$

It is clear from (1), (2) & (3) that the given equality holds for all positive integers $\color{blue}{n\geq 1}$